# Sending commands to CMD/MobaXterm via python

Tags: python, cmd, mobaxterm

I'm making an app via python with GUI.

I want to set a button that will connect to a specific path and run some commands at the server and leave the terminal open after he will finished running the commands.

I'm trying to send a several commands to CMD/MobaXterm with python,

I need to access a certain path with ssh, and add a command, like `ls -l`

Thanks.

Comment: you can create a bash file running and ssh directly to the server you want... why do you have to go through MobaXterm?

Comment: I'm making an app via python with gui,. I want to set a button that will connect to a  specific path and run some commands at the server.